# Power BI - how to add checkbox to a table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am searching, but so far I couldn't find a solid answer to this question. There are some old answers, but I wonder if the situation is still same.

Here is my question; I have a table in Power BI - lets assume its a list of grocery items.
I want to add a checkbox column to the table on the Report View pane, and check the ones I bought, so that next time I use the list, I can see the items I bought before.

I put the strike through just to emphasise, I wanna change value of Lemon row from False, to True on Report View pane.

| Grocery Item | Market | Quantity | Checkbox |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tomato | Migros | 7 | False |
| <strike>Lemon</strike> | <strike>Onur</strike> | <strike>3</strike> | True |
| Lettuce | Migros | 2 | False |
| Potato | A101 | 5 | False |

I tried adding a checkbox column, and changing the values on Report View, but apparently I have to go to Power Query Editor to edit the source data. But I wanna share the report view, not the data itself. It creates an impasse.

Comment: As you wrote, Power BI does not support any changes to the data inside the data model in “DAX mode” (when all the interaction with the visuals is happening), except for the data upload and mashup via PowerQuery (which is the step before DAX). That been said, you may want to search for some possible workarounds via Power App. Another option: It’s not exactly the same, and I don’t think it’s “directly/immediately” applicable for your use case, there is also the possibility to enter (PowerQuery) parameter values in DAX mode and to trigger a refresh of the data model.

Comment: thank you for the info. Can you elaborate your last suggestion a bit more? It might be a work around.